# signal construction based on cross correlation

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection

Consider we have to design a signal $
\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^{1_{} \times N_{\mathrm{}}}
$ that needs to have the lowest correlation with an unknown signal $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C}^{1_{} \times N_{\mathrm{}}}:
$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
\text { minimize } & E\left[\mathbf{x}_{} \mathbf{y}^{H}_{}\right] \\
\text { subject to } & \mathbf{x}_{} \mathbf{x}^{H}_{}=1
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Is it optimum to make $\mathbf{x}$ to be Gaussian?  I am trying to prove that based on Entropy of $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: no, it wouldn't be more optimal than any other choice.

Comment: The application of the expectation operator $E[\cdot]$, you will have to tell us your stochastic model of $\mathbf y$, otherwise no statement can be made. Also, $\mathbf x\mathbf y^H$ is not lower-bounded, you sure you don't want to minimize $E\left[\left\lvert \mathbf x \mathbf y^H\right\rvert\right]$?

Comment: I think you are right. I need to lower bound it. Assume $\mathbf{y}$ is colored Gaussian.

Comment: That's a central statement, please specify that in your question instead of just in the comments. I still don't understand what exactly you're trying to optimize, if it's not $E[\mathbf x \mathbf y^H]$. Does the coloredness of the noise relate different entries of $\mathbf y$ to each other, or different $\mathbf y$? I think we'll make the quickest progress if you write down, as formally correct as possible, what you actually want to optimize, and what exactly your stochastic model is.